# sharepoint Custom List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom list, I cannot delete the title column from it. Is there any way I can delete the title column. I know title column is used to edit the item itself. But when some one tries to insert a new record title column comes up. Is there any way I can atleast hide the title column.

Thank you
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to your List settings > Advanced settings > Allow Management of Content Types = Yes.

Now go back to your List Settings, you should see the Content Type "Item". Click on it. There you will see the "Title" Column, which you can click on again and set to "Hidden":

[image]

This process is explained in more detail here: [How to remove the “title” column from a SharePoint list](http://www.dlocc.com/articles/how-to-remove-title-column-from-sharepoint-list/) or a complete version here: [Hide Columns in SharePoint New, Edit and Disp Forms](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2010/02/16/hide-columns-in-sharepoint-new-edit-and-disp-forms/)